# Can't convert from Celcius to Fahrenheit in Android emulator

Tags: android, if-statement

It works when I convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius but it doesn't work when I try to convert it back from Celsius into Fahrenheit. I've tried for so many times but it still doesn't work for me.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.converter_second);

    rb_celcius = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton_celcius);
    rb_fahrenheit = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2_fahrenheit);
    btn_convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3_convert);
    btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5_clear);
    edTxt_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_amount);
    txtVw_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7_answer);

    btn_convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double dblFahrenheit = 0;
            double dblCelcius = (5.0 / 9) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
            double dblConvertedTemp = 0;
            double dblFahConversion;
            if (v == btn_convert) {
                if (rb_celcius.isChecked()) {
                    String strFah = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
                    if (!strFah.isEmpty()) {
                        {
                            dblFahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(strFah);
                        }
                        if (dblFahrenheit <= 212) {
                            dblConvertedTemp = (5.0 / 9.0) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
                            txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is " + dblConvertedTemp);

                        } if (rb_fahrenheit.isChecked()) {
                            String strCel = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
                            if (!strCel.isEmpty()) {
                                {
                                    dblCelcius = Double.parseDouble(strCel);
                                }
                                if (dblCelcius <= 100) {
                                    dblFahConversion = dblCelcius * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
                                    txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is" + dblFahConversion);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (v == btn_clear){
                                rg_group.clearCheck();
                                txtVw_answer.setText("");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if the logic is correct, but from what I see, the braces are all wrong. This is also not the best way of writing this solution, I will leave that to you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.converter_second);

    rb_celcius = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton_celcius);
    rb_fahrenheit = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2_fahrenheit);
    btn_convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3_convert);
    btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5_clear);
    edTxt_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_amount);
    txtVw_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7_answer);

    btn_convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double dblFahrenheit = 0;
            double dblCelcius = (5.0 / 9) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
            double dblConvertedTemp = 0;
            double dblFahConversion;
            if (v == btn_convert) {
                if (rb_celcius.isChecked()) {
                    String strFah = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
                    if (!strFah.isEmpty()) {
                            dblFahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(strFah);
                    }
                    if (dblFahrenheit <= 212) {
                        dblConvertedTemp = (5.0 / 9.0) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
                        txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is " + dblConvertedTemp);

                    }
                }

                if (rb_fahrenheit.isChecked()) {
                        String strCel = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
                        if (!strCel.isEmpty()) {
                                dblCelcius = Double.parseDouble(strCel);
                        }
                        if (dblCelcius <= 100) {
                            dblFahConversion = dblCelcius * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
                            txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is" + dblFahConversion);
                        } else if (v == btn_clear){
                            rg_group.clearCheck();
                            txtVw_answer.setText("");
                        }

                }
            }
        }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation and use of braces makes it quite hard to see the problem. If I fix the indentation, I get the following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

double dblFahrenheit = 0;
double dblCelcius = (5.0 / 9) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
double dblConvertedTemp = 0;
double dblFahConversion;
if (v == btn_convert) {
    if (rb_celcius.isChecked()) {
        String strFah = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
        if (!strFah.isEmpty()) {
            {
                dblFahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(strFah);
            }
            if (dblFahrenheit <= 212) {
                dblConvertedTemp = (5.0 / 9.0) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
                txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is " + dblConvertedTemp);

            } 
            if (rb_fahrenheit.isChecked()) {
                String strCel = edTxt_amount.getText().toString();
                if (!strCel.isEmpty()) {
                    {
                        dblCelcius = Double.parseDouble(strCel);
                    }
                    if (dblCelcius <= 100) {
                        dblFahConversion = dblCelcius * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
                        txtVw_answer.setText("The answer is" + dblFahConversion);
                    }
                }
                else if (v == btn_clear){
                    rg_group.clearCheck();
                    txtVw_answer.setText("");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think it does not work because you check if rb_fahrenheit is checked within the if block that is executed when rb_celcius is checked. Given the fact that these views are radiobuttons, I assume that they reside in the same RadioGroup in which case both radiobuttons have to be checked. This is impossible for a RadioGroup. This explains why the other way around does not work. From the looks of it, the code itself should work.